# How to get attributes of model in has_many :through association in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, model, has-many-through

So I have 2 models in a has_many :through association. The two models are Meal and Food. Basically a Meal can have multiple food items and a food item can be a part of many meals. The third join model is called meal_foods.
I have set it up so that when you are creating a new Meal you can choose via a checkbox all the food items for the meal. A food item has attributes like calories & proteins and the Meal has attributes like total_calories and total_proteins.
How can I make it so that when making a new Meal I can calculate the values of all the attributes (calories, proteins, etc.) of all the food items?

Here's my code so far:

**Models**

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :meal_foods
    has_many :foods, through: :meal_foods
end

class Food < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :meal_foods
    has_many :meals, through: :meal_foods
end

class MealFood < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :meal
    belongs_to :food
end
```

**Meals Controller**

```
    def create
        @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)
        @meal.user_id = current_user.id

        @meal.total_calories = #Implement code here...

        if @meal.save
            redirect_to @meal
        else
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
```

**Meals View (Create action)**

```
    <%= form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :meal_type %>
            <%= f.select :meal_type, ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Morning Snack", "Afternoon Snack, Evening Snack"] %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <% Food.all.each do |food| %>
                <%= check_box_tag "meal[food_ids][]", food.id %>
                <%= food.name %>
            <% end %>
                </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.submit class: "button button-highlight button-block" %>
       </div>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum` eg for calories:

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :meal_foods
    has_many :foods, through: :meal_foods

    def total_calories
      foods.sum(:calories)
    end
end
```

Sum works on any numeric column in an association.

If for some you need to store the value in the db (eg you're going to sort meals based on caloric content and it's easier to store the value), then you can instead tell a meal that when it is created, it should calculate and store the calories eg:

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :meal_foods
    has_many :foods, through: :meal_foods

    # Tells rails to run this method when each Meal is first created
    after_create :store_total_calories

    # actually calculates the number of calories for any given meal (can be used even after saving in the db eg if the calories changed)
    def calculate_total_calories
      foods.sum(:calories)
    end

    # calculates, then resaves the updated value   
    def store_total_calories
       update(total_calories: calculate_total_calories)
    end
end
```

Note: more on the [`after_create` callback here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

Note: nothing needs to be done in the controller for this to all Just Work.

Comment: Will that do the sum of the calories of the food items for only the meal they're in?

Comment: Yes. it will sum the calories for the food-items for the given meal - because it uses the `foods` of the meal itself and it is an instance method.

Comment: Great, but I don't understand how to implement it. I add the method and then what? Where do I use this method?

Comment: Using `@meal.total_calories` as you had in your example :)

Comment: Sorry for the many questions, I'm just very new to ruby, but so I have to do this: @meal.total_calories = total_calories?

Comment: NP: we all started there at some point :) No, you don't need to assign anything to meal.total_calories... it will calculate the calories for you on the fly based on the foods that belong to the meal. :) You just use `meal.total_calories` and it runs the method that I have written above to display the number of calories for the meal.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to be working. The calories attribute is in the foods table and the total_calories attribute is in the meals table. Should I add the calories attribute in the join model table (meal_foods)?

Comment: Have you created a new meal? This example looks solid but will only persist the meal's total calories upon creating the meal. You could also call `meal.store_total_calories` to set the calories for an existing meal or `calculate_total_calories` to read the sum of `foods.calories`. There are also different callbacks in the link provided above which can execute at other points in time such as when the meal is updated with new foods.